# YouTube Data API (v3) search pagination, return "items" empty

Tags: json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

API request with parameters used:

**["items" OK]**

part=id

channelId=UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A

key=[API KEY]

maxResults=50

pageToken=CIkCEAE

Response json:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/fRLRzDJR1r68v6VuXm7NWw28YHw\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CIkCEAA",
 "prevPageToken": "CNcBEAE",
 "regionCode": "BR",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 335,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/88OMvV6T3kqFzrIZjG-5CBCAyEM\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "gf-L6JkFXjA"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/XNCA6m3Cej2vCZXp6ad_XdO-RRU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "2wVzOw13t0Q"
  }
  }
 ]
}
```

Return Ok, check parameter exist "nextPageToken", for capture next page:

New request parameters:

**["items" empty]**

part=id

channelId=UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A

key=[API KEY]

maxResults=50

pageToken=CIkCEAA

Response json:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/SgHCPDU8UCvUHeC9Mc-IXFn8mrA\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CLsCEAA",
 "prevPageToken": "CIkCEAE",
 "regionCode": "BR",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 335,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Online test developers.google.com:

```
"items" OK -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params={%22part%22:%22id%22,%22channelId%22:%22UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A%22,%22maxResults%22:50,%22pageToken%22:%22CIkCEAE%22}

"items" Empty -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params={%22part%22:%22id%22,%22channelId%22:%22UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A%22,%22maxResults%22:50,%22pageToken%22:%22CIkCEAA%22}
```

*** Credentials not used Google OAuth 2.0

Comment: Please fix your formatting and post your code.  What error are you getting? If your getting credentials not used then its a code issue your not sending the bearer token with your request.

Answer (score 0):

It might happen something wrong with YouTube official documentation's demo feature in their page.

If you try the same request in Google API explorer, you'll get the items in the next/previous pages.

> N.B I have face similar situations where in the YouTube's official
>   documentation page does not work, but, by testing the same request in
>   Google Data API, it works as expected.

My advice is, next time you face a similar situation, try in these places:

- Test your request(s) in the YouTube official deocumentation page.
- Test your request(s) in Google API Explorer.
- Test your request(s) in your website, API, page, etcétera.

Example - page 1 of you request using the given `channel_id` **`UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A`**.

- URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2C+snippet&channelId=UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A&maxResults=50&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(channelId%2CchannelTitle%2Cdescription%2CpublishedAt%2Ctitle))%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
- Page 1 - [link demo in Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252C%20snippet&channelId=UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A&maxResults=50&fields=items(id%252Csnippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle%252Cdescription%252CpublishedAt%252Ctitle))%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CregionCode%252CtokenPagination&_h=1&).
- Results of page 1:

---

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "regionCode": "CO",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 335,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Qq5e5EJjeVo"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-08-06T21:03:15.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "PART3 vs LUDERKING DESGRADIUS FROG VS MACHINE GENEX Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "JOGO 1- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGV0B6WzFv8&t=432s JOGO 2-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWgIJzQCAaU JOGO 3 NO CANAL DO ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Mw-OO_OVIcE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-07-08T17:29:53.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "ANALISE NOVO PACK/ ANALISING NEW PACK Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "LINK DO LOOTS/SUPER CHAT GRATIS-https://loots.com/en/tip-jars/migueljoker LINK DO NOSSO DISCORD/OUR FREE DISCORD https://discord.gg/ycdzdsD ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "zYWvmqyqj3k"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-04-03T13:53:33.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "Tudo Sobre Misstiming!! Nao perca para Ag Nem Yubel!! Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "Ajude o Canal com Paypal- migueljokerduelinks@gmail.com Manahen Canal ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "HMlCUz25NsU"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-16T03:08:45.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "TOP 1 KC GLOBAL/ Back to Worlds? De Volta ao Mundial? Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "Pagina Facebook- https://www.facebook.com/migueljokerduelinks/ Latino America- https://www.facebook.com/groups/340304503003946/ LINK DO ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  [more videos here...],
 ]
}
```

---

- URL - page 2 (*using the `pageToken` value*): `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2C+snippet&channelId=UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A&maxResults=50&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(channelId%2CchannelTitle%2Cdescription%2CpublishedAt%2Ctitle))%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
- Page 2 - [link demo in Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252C%20snippet&channelId=UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A&maxResults=50&pageToken=CDIQAA&fields=items(id%252Csnippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle%252Cdescription%252CpublishedAt%252Ctitle))%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CregionCode%252CtokenPagination&_h=1&).
- Results of page 2:

---

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "nextPageToken": "CGQQAA",
 "prevPageToken": "CDIQAQ",
 "regionCode": "CO",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 335,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "LEMjPqqWvy8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-05-28T10:57:47.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "Six Samurai Ainda Forte!! Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "Ajude o Canal com Paypal- migueljokerduelinks@gmail.com Manahen Canal ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "UZXQa3SSy5M"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-22T23:13:05.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "Novo Deck Fenix Bom ou Bosta? New Fenix is it worth it?Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "Pagina Facebook- https://www.facebook.com/migueljokerduelinks/ Latino America- https://www.facebook.com/groups/340304503003946/ LINK DO ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "lNDxWeFgOYI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-04-06T15:13:45.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "Melhor Counter de Six Sams!! Best Six Sam  Counter!! Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "Ajude o Canal com Paypal- migueljokerduelinks@gmail.com Manahen Canal ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "OP9JTktNEhg"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-03-02T01:03:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxA5VFvNdlGUTingA9jMu3A",
    "title": "Last  Gamble Cancer Kog Dia1!! 100% Vitoria vs Koaki!! Yu-gi-oh Duel Links",
    "description": "AJ- CANAL https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZaEOV0fMJBEamZ8K-jPE3A Pagina Facebook- https://www.facebook.com/migueljokerduelinks/ Latino ...",
    "channelTitle": "Miguel Joker Duelinks"
   }
  },
  [more videos here...],
 ]
}
```